# Java - How to increase the robot delay above 60'000 milliseconds?

Tags: java, awtrobot

Im trying to make an Auto Typer but i cant go above 60'000 milliseconds between each message, is it possible to go above that?

Code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class Runnah implements Runnable {

    private MainGUI gui;

    // A new robot
    private Robot robot;

    private boolean toggle;

    private static boolean enter;

    public Runnah(MainGUI c) throws AWTException {
        // Creates the Robot
        this.robot = new Robot();
        // Sets the current GUI
        gui = c;
        toggle = true;
        enter = false;
    }

    public Runnah(Robot robot) {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    private void typeNow(int... key) {
        typeNow(key, 0, key.length);
    }

    private void typeNow(int[] key, int offset, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Presses and releases the key that is passed into typeNow
        robot.keyPress(key[offset]);
        typeNow(key, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(key[offset]);
    }

    // GIANT SWITCH STATEMENT FOR EVERY CHARACTER ON THE KEYBOARD
    public void typeThis(char let) {
        switch (let) {
        case 'a':
            typeNow(VK_A);
            break;
        case 'b':
            typeNow(VK_B);
            break;
        case 'c':
            typeNow(VK_C);
            break;
        case 'd':
            typeNow(VK_D);
            break;
        case 'e':
            typeNow(VK_E);
            break;
        case 'f':
            typeNow(VK_F);
            break;
        case 'g':
            typeNow(VK_G);
            break;
        case 'h':
            typeNow(VK_H);
            break;
        case 'i':
            typeNow(VK_I);
            break;
        case 'j':
            typeNow(VK_J);
            break;
        case 'k':
            typeNow(VK_K);
            break;
        case 'l':
            typeNow(VK_L);
            break;
        case 'm':
            typeNow(VK_M);
            break;
        case 'n':
            typeNow(VK_N);
            break;
        case 'o':
            typeNow(VK_O);
            break;
        case 'p':
            typeNow(VK_P);
            break;
        case 'q':
            typeNow(VK_Q);
            break;
        case 'r':
            typeNow(VK_R);
            break;
        case 's':
            typeNow(VK_S);
            break;
        case 't':
            typeNow(VK_T);
            break;
        case 'u':
            typeNow(VK_U);
            break;
        case 'v':
            typeNow(VK_V);
            break;
        case 'w':
            typeNow(VK_W);
            break;
        case 'x':
            typeNow(VK_X);
            break;
        case 'y':
            typeNow(VK_Y);
            break;
        case 'z':
            typeNow(VK_Z);
            break;
        case 'A':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_A);
            break;
        case 'B':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_B);
            break;
        case 'C':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_C);
            break;
        case 'D':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_D);
            break;
        case 'E':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_E);
            break;
        case 'F':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_F);
            break;
        case 'G':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_G);
            break;
        case 'H':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_H);
            break;
        case 'I':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_I);
            break;
        case 'J':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_J);
            break;
        case 'K':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_K);
            break;
        case 'L':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_L);
            break;
        case 'M':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_M);
            break;
        case 'N':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_N);
            break;
        case 'O':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_O);
            break;
        case 'P':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_P);
            break;
        case 'Q':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_Q);
            break;
        case 'R':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_R);
            break;
        case 'S':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_S);
            break;
        case 'T':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_T);
            break;
        case 'U':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_U);
            break;
        case 'V':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_V);
            break;
        case 'W':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_W);
            break;
        case 'X':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_X);
            break;
        case 'Y':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_Y);
            break;
        case 'Z':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_Z);
            break;
        case '`':
            typeNow(VK_BACK_QUOTE);
            break;
        case '0':
            typeNow(VK_0);
            break;
        case '1':
            typeNow(VK_1);
            break;
        case '2':
            typeNow(VK_2);
            break;
        case '3':
            typeNow(VK_3);
            break;
        case '4':
            typeNow(VK_4);
            break;
        case '5':
            typeNow(VK_5);
            break;
        case '6':
            typeNow(VK_6);
            break;
        case '7':
            typeNow(VK_7);
            break;
        case '8':
            typeNow(VK_8);
            break;
        case '9':
            typeNow(VK_9);
            break;
        case '-':
            typeNow(VK_MINUS);
            break;
        case '=':
            typeNow(VK_EQUALS);
            break;
        case '~':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_QUOTE);
            break;
        case '!':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_1);
            break;
        case '@':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_2);
            break;
        case '#':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_3);
            break;
        case '$':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_4);
            break;
        case '%':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_5);
            break;
        case '^':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_6);
            break;
        case '&':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_7);
            break;
        case '*':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_8);
            break;
        case '(':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_9);
            break;
        case ')':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_0);
            break;
        case '_':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_MINUS);
            break;
        case '+':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_EQUALS);
            break;
        case '\t':
            typeNow(VK_TAB);
            break;
        case '\n':
            typeNow(VK_ENTER);
            break;
        case '[':
            typeNow(VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
            break;
        case ']':
            typeNow(VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
            break;
        case '\\':
            typeNow(VK_BACK_SLASH);
            break;
        case '{':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
            break;
        case '}':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_CLOSE_BRACKET);
            break;
        case '|':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_BACK_SLASH);
            break;
        case ';':
            typeNow(VK_SEMICOLON);
            break;
        case ':':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_SEMICOLON);
            break;
        case '\'':
            typeNow(VK_QUOTE);
            break;
        case '"':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_QUOTE);
            break;
        case ',':
            typeNow(VK_COMMA);
            break;
        case '<':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMA);
            break;
        case '.':
            typeNow(VK_PERIOD);
            break;
        case '>':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_PERIOD);
            break;
        case '/':
            typeNow(VK_SLASH);
            break;
        case '?':
            typeNow(VK_SHIFT, VK_SLASH);
            break;
        case ' ':
            typeNow(VK_SPACE);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Derp! That chatacter doesn't work " + let);
        }
    }

    public void setToggle() {
        toggle = false;
    }

    // Enables/Disables the enter key
    public void setEnter(boolean a) {
        enter = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int seconds = 1;

        // Get the input from the textField in the GUI
        String temp = gui.getInput();

        // Turns it into an array of chars
        char[] test = new char[temp.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            test[i] = temp.charAt(i);
        }

        // Sets the seconds to the entered seconds * 1000
        // Becase .delay() runs in Milliseconds
        try {
            seconds = gui.getSeconds() * 1000;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            robot.delay(seconds);

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
                typeThis(test[i]);
            }

            if (enter) {
                typeNow(VK_ENTER);
            }
        }
        toggle = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code instead of linking it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Original Version :

```
    try {
        seconds = gui.getSeconds() * 1000;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        robot.delay(seconds);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            typeThis(test[i]);
        }

        if (enter) {
            typeNow(VK_ENTER);
        }
    }
```

Fixed Version :

```
    try {
        seconds = gui.getSeconds() * 1000;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.print(seconds);
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        if (seconds <= 60000) {
            robot.delay(seconds);
        } else {
            try {
                int newTime = seconds - 60000;
                robot.delay(60000);
                Thread.sleep(newTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            typeThis(test[i]);
        }

        if (enter) {
            typeNow(VK_ENTER);
        }
    }
```

Allows you to go above 60'000 ms delay.